# Wi-Fi Service not displayed in the "Add Service" option list in Macbook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

The problem I am having is similar to [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283368/wifi-network-option-is-not-showing-up).
The thing is that all the answers says I should run Apple hardware test. I tried that, the "press D" boot and the "press Opt+D" boot. In both cases, during the boot, the system tries to connect to internet, and since I don't have internet connection, the **error 1005D** is displayed.

Using `networksetup -listallhardwareports` command, the wifi port is not listed (only bluetooth PAN, Thunderbolt 1 and Thunderbolt Bridge are displayed). Does this mean that my wifi card adapter is dead? I assume that's the case, just want to be 100% sure before ordering a replacement, since it's an old mac, and I'm out of warranty. Thanks!