# Unable to turn on WiFi on iMac

Tags: macos, wifi, imac

I keep around a 27" iMac Core 2 Duo (10,1) on my home network for continued access to 32-bit apps. One HD partition (and Safe Mode) can turn on my WiFi/Airport, whereas a second partition containing El Capitan reports that the WiFi is "off". No matter what I try, I can't get WiFi enabled. As a result I can't scan for or join any wireless networks.(I gave up a year or so ago and began connecting over ethernet but the iMac is being moved to a location where I can't do that anymore and I need the airport, screen and file sharing features to to function.)

System Profiler sees that the WiFi card is installed (detected) but Wireless Diagnostics isn't able to turn the WiFi on and complete a report. I have pursued the usual suspects such as deleting Library/Preferences/System Configuration plist files, zapping the PRAM, SMU reset, turning off firewalls, removing antivirus, disabling apps that launch at login, using Terminal to turn the WiFi/Airport on, changing locations, attempting to connect via a guest account, verifying that no unauthorized proxies exist, etc. Essentially everything I have tried is outlined [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283368/wifi-network-option-is-not-showing-up), in a prior question.

I recently tried reinstalling El Capitan to fix this and still no luck. My last thought was to run Apple Hardware Test (basic test found nothing relevant so I'm currently running the extended version). After this, I'm flat out of ideas. Am I missing anything?